# Object array dynamic

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following line in my code:

```
object[] inputs = new object[] {"input1", "input2", "input3", "input4"};
```

I would like to know how (without knowing how many elements will be in the array) add dynamically using a loop like this:

```
object[] inputs;
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
     inputs[0] = key;
}
```

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you just not use:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Add(key);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like the [`IEnumerable.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) function.

```
object[] inputs = Request.Form.Keys.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `List<T>` it has same access efficiency as array (`O(1)`) and have method `Add` to add elements. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx